# Extract week number from character varying column where dates are in float values as well as in datetimestamp as well

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in which the closure_date which is represented as a character varying column. Some of the dates are saved as "43684.5708564815" and also as "2019-05-24 18:51:17". Now I need to extract the week number from the column. I tried the following the query :

```
 SELECT closure_date, 
 extract('week' from timestamp '1899-12-30' + interval '1 day' * cast(closure_date as  double 
 precision)) as closure_week,
 FROM <table_name>
 LIMIT 10000
```

This query runs fine for values like  43684.5708564815 however result into an error while trying to extract the week_number from "2019-05-24 18:51:17" stating :

```
 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "2019-05-24 18:51:17"
 SQL state: 22P02
```

How to handle the error? Any suggestions?

Comment: You can check if closure_date is a date. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374707/check-whether-string-is-a-date-postgresql

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression with a regex to test if the string is formatted like an ISO date or not:

```
SELECT closure_date, 
       case 
         when closure_date ~ '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9:]{8}' 
           then extract(week from closure_date::timestamp)
         else
           extract('week' from timestamp '1899-12-30' + (interval '1 day' * cast(closure_date as double precision))) 
        end as closure_week
FROM <table_name>
```

The `~` operator compares the `closure_date` with the regular expression to see if it matches that pattern.

Note that if you have different formats, this could still fail and you need to add more checks.

---

If you have the chance, you should really change that column to be a `timestamp` rather than keeping this badly formatted string.

Comment: Can you please explain the significance of using '1234.56', as my answer comes fine when I use "cast(closure_date as  double precision)" instead of using "'1234.56'::double precision"

Comment: @AmanRaparia: the `1234.56` was a left over from my tests and a copy & paste error.

Comment: the answer worked perfectly for me. Yes we wanted to correct the column to 'timestamp', however the data that comes in very bad shape and we finally decided to dump the data as is and then fetch from it using custom queries. Do you suggest we should use triggers while inserting the records.

Comment: Also if you liked the question you can upvote as well.